# How order a multidimensional array for multiple key?

Tags: php

```
How order an array so structured for [name] and to parity of [name] for [age] ?

    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mary
            [age] => 32
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mary
            [age] => 31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Anna
            [age] => 30
        )

Output: 

Name | Age
----------
Anna | 30
Mary | 31
Mary | 32
```

This is code:

```
function sort(&$array) {
  function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) { 
      return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]); 
    };
  }
  usort($array, build_sorter(["name"]));            
  usort($array, build_sorter(["age"]));         
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific and show your expected output. Also, show what code you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: you want to sort the array by name and age both??

Comment: yes, so. I have update post with code too.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this function

```
<?php 
function Func_Sort($arr, $index) {
    $b = array();
    $c = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $b[$key] = $value[$index];
    }

    asort($b);

    foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
        $c[] = $arr[$key];
    }

    return $c;
}
$activities = array (
    '1' => array(
        'name' => 'Mary',
        'age' => 32,

    ),
    '2' => array(
        'name' => 'Mary',
        'age' => 31,
        ),
    '3' => array(
        'name' => 'anna',
        'age' => 30
    ), 
);
$sorted_act = Func_Sort($activities, 'age');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($sorted_act);

?>
```

demo link : http://codepad.org/VNXbCjsT

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

*Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function*

**Example #4**

```
<?php
  $array[0] = array('key_a' => 'z', 'key_b' => 'c');
  $array[1] = array('key_a' => 'x', 'key_b' => 'b');
  $array[2] = array('key_a' => 'y', 'key_b' => 'a');

  function build_sorter($key) {
   return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
       return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
   };
  }

  usort($array, build_sorter('key_b'));

  foreach ($array as $item) {
     echo $item['key_a'] . ', ' . $item['key_b'] . "\n";
  }

?>
```

Comment: Return an "Illegal offset type" at this line: "return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]); ". Structure of array is as above in post.